# Weird behavior with Promise throwing "Unhandled promise rejection" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

When I run this code using Node, it throws an `Unhandled promise rejection` error in the console (even showing the `error caught` text first).

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000))
promise.then(() => console.log('ok'))
promise.catch((e) => console.log('error caught'))
```

Nevertheless, when I chain the `catch` method to the `then` method, the error disappears:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000))
promise.then(() => console.log('ok')).catch((e) => console.log('error caught'))
```

Isn't the first code supposed to handle the rejection?

I also tried the first code in Chrome and it works if I open the inspector when I'm in a new tab (or google.com). If I'm in any other page (like stackoverflow.com) it throws the exception. Any explanation to this? This seems really weird to me!

Comment: In the first, both `.then()` and `.catch()` create a promise. Only on one of them the rejection was handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be considered handled, rejected promises should be synchronously chained with `then(..., ...)` (2 arguments) or `catch(...)`.

`promise.then(() => console.log('ok'))` is a separate promise that wasn't chained with  `catch(...)`, so rejected promise will result in unhandled rejection.

> If I'm in any other page (like stackoverflow.com) it throws the exception

This isn't an exception, it doesn't prevent a script from running normally. The way unhandled rejections are treated depends on `Promise` implementation. Chrome implementation results in `Uncaught (in promise)` console error by default.

That it doesn't appear on some websites in Chrome means that a website set up [`unhandledrejection` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) handler that suppresses error output.